# Why is this code correct while it should clearly run into an infinite loop?

Tags: binary-heap

I have been having a problem with this code for a while. The placement of recursive call of the function does not seem right.

i tried running the code and yes it does run into a infinite loop.

```
// I DEFINE HEAP STRUCTURE AS :
struct heap_array
{
  int *array;  // heap implementation using arrays(note : heap is atype of a tree).

  int capacity;  // how much the heap can hold.
  int size;   //how much size is currently occupied.

void MaxHeapify(struct heap_array *h,int loc)  // note : loc is the location of element to be PERCOLATED DOWN.
{
  int left,right,max_loc=loc;
  left=left_loc_child(h,loc);
  right=right_loc_child(h,loc);

  if(left !=-1 && h->array[left]>h->array[loc])
  {
    max_loc=left;
  }

  if(right!=-1 && h->array[right]>h->array[max_loc])
  {
    max_loc=right;
  }

  if(max_loc!=loc)  //i.e. if changes were made:
  {
    //swap the element at max_loc and loc
    int temp=h->array[max_loc];
    h->array[max_loc]=h->array[loc];
    h->array[loc]=temp;


  }
    MaxHeapify(h,max_loc); // <-- i feel that this recursive call is misplaced. I have seen the exact same code in almost all the online videos and some books i referred to. ALSO I THINK THAT THE CALL SHOULD BE MADE WITHIN THE SCOPE OF condition if(max_loc!=loc).
    //if no changes made, end the func right there.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current implementation, it looks like you don't have a base case for recursion to stop.

Remember that [you need a base case in a recursive function](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/) (in this case, your `MaxHeapify` function), and it doesn't look like there is one.

[Here is an example of MaxHeap](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/max-heap-in-java/) which may be resourceful to look at

```
// A recursive function to max heapify the given 
    // subtree. This function assumes that the left and 
    // right subtrees are already heapified, we only need 
    // to fix the root. 
    private void maxHeapify(int pos) 
    { 
        if (isLeaf(pos)) 
            return; 

        if (Heap[pos] < Heap[leftChild(pos)] ||  
            Heap[pos] < Heap[rightChild(pos)]) { 

            if (Heap[leftChild(pos)] > Heap[rightChild(pos)]) { 
                swap(pos, leftChild(pos)); 
                maxHeapify(leftChild(pos)); 
            } 
            else { 
                swap(pos, rightChild(pos)); 
                maxHeapify(rightChild(pos)); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Here, you can see the basecase of:

```
    if (isLeaf(pos)) 
        return;
```

You need to add a base case to your recursive function.

Comment: I understand what u meant. I DO need a base condition, but the above code is not mine but the code popularly shown in many books and online lessons while it is wrong. About the base condition , wont it be correct if just call the heapify function if any changes were made that is the condt. if(max_loc!=loc) is TRUE ??

Comment: I had another doubt, the above code(assume it is correct) wont heapify the entire heap ,right?, as there might still be some index which does not follow MAX heap condt,

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show where that code is located? I don't remember seeing it anywhere I have looked. And as for your questions, the above code would NOT heapify the entire heap in its current state, but I believe because that is a code segment. If you click on the GeeksforGeeks link I posted, that shows a complete example that would. Additionally, just that conditional would not satisfy a base case, as you are still editing the heap in every possible condition, so there is no return statement.

Comment: Thanks! i saw the code in a book called DS made easy by narasimha , on youtube channel like Saurabh Shukla and some more. I hve only changed the names , rest is same. :)